# Nhibernate creating object which has an object property

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm just starting to work with NHibernate. I have two objects:

```
public class Supplier 
{
    public virtual int id{get;set;}
    public virtual SupplierAddress address{get;set;}
    public virtual string Name{get;set;}
}
public class SupplierAddress 
{
    public virtual int id{get;set;}
    public virtual Supplier{get;set;}
    public virtual string SupplierAddressLine{get;set;}
}
```

When I want to create a new `Supplier` I create a new object:

```
var supplierAddress = new SupplierAddress {
    SupplierAddressLine = "someLine"
}

var supplier = new Supplier 
{
    Name = "someName",
    SupplierAddress = SupplierAddressLine 
}
```

Then, when i try to save using:

```
_session.Save(supplier);
```

I get the error: "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'id'

### Update 1 Mappings

for SupplierAddress

---

```
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("Id");
        References(x => x.Supplier).Column("SupplierId");
        Map(x => x.AddressLine1).Column("AddressLine1").Not.Nullable().Length(255);
```

for Supplier

---

```
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("Id");
        References(x => x.SupplierAddress).Column("SupplierAddressId").Not.Nullable();
        HasMany(x => x.SupplierAddresses).KeyColumn("SupplierId");
```

Comment: Can you show your mappings for the classes?

Comment: try to set protected set in id's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set some [cascade rules](http://ayende.com/blog/1890/nhibernate-cascades-the-different-between-all-all-delete-orphans-and-save-update) on the `Supplier` → `SupplierAddress` relationship:

```
References(s => s.SupplierAddress)
    .Column("SupplierAddressId")
    .Not.Nullable()
    .Cascade.All(); /* Cascade operations that happen on `Supplier` */
```

Otherwise, NHibernate does not know that saving the parent (`Supplier`) should also save the child (`SupplierAddress`)

**Edit:** I think you're actually using `References` incorrectly here.

In a mapping, when you say an entity `References` another, you're basically telling NHibernate that ***the other side of this relationship is a `HasMany`***.

In your case, neither `Supplier` nor `SupplierAddress` actually has many `SupplierAddress`es or `Supplier`s, respectively.

With that in mind, you probably mean one of two things:

1. A `SupplierAddress` is shared by multiple `Suppliers`. This would mean that `SupplierAddress` actually *has many* `Suppliers`, but a `Supplier` only has one `SupplierAddress`.

   In the C# class, this would mean that `SupplierAddress` has a collection of `Suppliers` (OR has no reference to `Supplier` at all).

   In this case, your database tables would look like this:

   ```sql
   create table [SupplierAddress]
   (
       [Id] int identity(1,1) primary key clustered,
       [AddressLine1] nvarchar(255) not null
   );
   create table [Supplier]
   (
       [Id] int identity(1,1) primary key clustered,
       [SupplierAddressId] int not null references [SupplierAddress]([Id])
   )
   ```

   Your C# classes would look like this:

   ```
   public class Supplier
   {   
       public virtual int Id { get; set; }

       public virtual SupplierAddress SupplierAddress { get; set; }

       public virtual string Name { get; set; }
   }

   public class SupplierAddress
   {
       public virtual int Id { get; set; }

       public virtual string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
   }
   ```

   And your mappings would look like this:

   ```
   public class SupplierMap : ClassMap<Supplier>
   {
       public SupplierMap()
       {
           Id(s => s.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("Id");
           References(s => s.SupplierAddress)
               .Column("SupplierAddressId")
               .Cascade.All();
       }
   }

   public class SupplierAddressMap : ClassMap<SupplierAddress>
   {
       public SupplierAddressMap()
       {
           Id(s => s.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("Id");

           Map(s => s.AddressLine1)
               .Column("AddressLine1")
               .Not.Nullable()
               .Length(255);
       }
   }
   ```
2. A `Supplier` has one `SupplierAddress`, and a `SupplierAddress` is only ever associated with one `Supplier`. Another way to think of this is that the entire `SupplierAddress` table could be logically merged into `Supplier`.

   In this case, your database tables would look like this:

   ```sql
   create table [SupplierAddress]
   (
       [Id] int identity(1,1) primary key clustered,
       [AddressLine1] nvarchar(255) not null,
       [SupplierId]  int not null
   );

   create table [Supplier]
   (
       [Id] int identity(1,1) primary key clustered,
       [SupplierAddressId] int references [SupplierAddress]([Id])
   );


   alter table [SupplierAddress] 
       add constraint [FK_SupplierAddress_Supplier] 
       foreign key ([SupplierId]) references [Supplier]([Id])
   ```

   Your C# classes would look like this:

   ```
   public class Supplier
   {   
       private SupplierAddress supplierAddress;

       public virtual int Id { get; set; }

       public virtual SupplierAddress SupplierAddress 
       {
           get { return this.supplierAddress; }
           set 
           { 
               this.supplierAddress = value;
               this.supplierAddress.Supplier = this;
           }
       }

       public virtual string Name { get; set; }
   }

   public class SupplierAddress
   {
       public virtual int Id { get; set; }

       public virtual string AddressLine1 { get; set; }

       public virtual Supplier Supplier { get; set; }
   }
   ```

   And your mappings would look like this:

   ```
   public class SupplierMap : ClassMap<Supplier>
   {
       public SupplierMap()
       {
           Id(s => s.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("Id");
           HasOne(s => s.SupplierAddress).PropertyRef(s => s.Supplier)
               .Access.CamelCaseField()
               .Cascade.All();
       }
   }

   public class SupplierAddressMap : ClassMap<SupplierAddress>
   {
       public SupplierAddressMap()
       {
           Id(s => s.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("Id");
           Map(s => s.AddressLine1).Column("AddressLine1");
           References(s => s.Supplier).Column("SupplierId").Unique();
       }
   }
   ```

   Note that when `Supplier.SupplierAddress` is `set`, the address's `Supplier` property is set.

Comment: it says that i should specufy Supplier Id in SupplierAddress table

Comment: @OlegDobra: So is `SupplierAddress.SupplierId` not nullable?

Comment: @OlegDobra: If both are not nullable, how is NHibernate supposed to insert them? If you were to try to insert `Supplier` first, you would fail because `SupplierAddress` does not exist yet. If you went to insert `SupplierAddress` first, that would fail since `Supplier` does not exist yet. I'd propose you remove the not null constraint from `SupplierAddress.SupplierId` or remove the reference from `SupplierAddress` to `Supplier` completely.

Comment: Thanks for your advise. in database there was no not nullable constraint. but i added it accidentally to mappings.